# starting bat file with test case but the cases are not executed

Tags: ide, selenium-ide

I tried to run the batch file but in all the aspects, turned out to be a failure.I use a FF4 version and ide 1.3.0  and also tried with FF 7.

Pls help to identify the issue.
The contents are.

java -jar selenium-server.jar -multiwindow -htmlSuite "*chrome" http://google.com "C:\Software\Reel\Reel Suit.html" "C:\Software\selenium-server-1.0.3\results\result.html"
pause

It runs and a firefox window opens but it terminates without the cases.
The result set is below.
I dont wanna do this without eclipse...

C:\selenium-remote-control-1.0.3\selenium-server-1.0.3>java -jar selenium-server
.jar -multiwindow -htmlSuite "*chrome" "http://localhost" "C:\Software\Reel
\Reel.html" "C:\selenium\test\result.html"
17:08:18.921 INFO - Java: Oracle Corporation 21.0-b17
17:08:18.921 INFO - OS: Windows XP 5.1 x86
17:08:18.921 INFO - v2.0 [a2], with Core v2.0 [a2]
17:08:19.046 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.
1:4444/wd/hub
17:08:19.046 INFO - Version Jetty/5.1.x
17:08:19.046 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server
/driver]
17:08:19.046 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
17:08:19.046 INFO - Started HttpContext[/,/]
17:08:19.078 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@fde050

17:08:19.078 INFO - Started HttpContext[/wd,/wd]
17:08:19.078 INFO - Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:4444
17:08:19.078 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@1b0889a
17:08:19.187 INFO - Preparing Firefox profile...
17:08:22.812 INFO - Launching Firefox...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try putting http://google.com in double-quotes like the following

java -jar selenium-server.jar -multiwindow -htmlSuite "*chrome" "http://google.com" "C:\Software\Reel\Reel Suit.html" "C:\Software\selenium-server-1.0.3\results\result.html"

Comment: No its not working. Its just the browser opens and is still for more than an hour.

Comment: yes.. I am using Ide version 1.3.0 and have installed selenium-remote-control-1.0.3.

Comment: Thats not the latest one... Selenium-2.8 is the one.. You can download the latest one here. [selenium - server](http://selenium.googlecode.com/files/selenium-server-standalone-2.8.0.jar)

Comment: Thanks for help but still i just wanna run the reports alone. I am not aware of web driver and the rc script. Its been just a few day's i started up with selenium. Is there any way that i can run this cause the one i installed has a bunch of selenium-remote-control folder. The one u gave has a jar file alone. Can you pls elaborate me. I am sorry that i am causing u trouble ...

Comment: The latest jar link that I shared can be used for all type scripts- html suites,RC scripts, webdriver and grid. You just use the new jar instead of the current 1.3.0 jar. The new jar supports latest version of browsers.  Also i dont think you need any other jars or folder for your execution ,as you just running the html suite.

Comment: My E-Mail ID is testreel1234@gmail.com. May i have your E-Mail Id pls if u feel free.

Comment: I got the things done except the error shows as "No test found with test runner junit 4" . I have started the server in command prompt too. Its in eclipse

Comment: I had sent you a mail to your id. Also what exactly you are trying to do? YOur original issue is running html suite through RC server. Now you have another issue after converting them to RC cases. This needs to be posted as a separate question.